# Accessing options properties inside for-each in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, template-engine

I was wondering in the following example how I can access the relevant `AttributeType` property of `$parent.contactFields`?

as $data looks up `fieldCouplings` not `$parent.contactFields`

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: fieldsCouplings">
   <li>
      <h5 data-bind="text: DisplayName"></h5>                            
      <label>Contact field: <select data-bind="options: $parent.contactFields, optionsText: $data.AttributeType"></select></label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I don't seem to be able to find any suitable Binding context in the docs too.

**I want to see optionsText to be 0, 1 and 2**

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/makeitmorehuman/86PqH/3/

Comment: I don't following you where is `AttributeType` defined? Can you create a small working repro in JSFiddle?

Comment: Ok but what should be the expected result? What do you want to see in the dropdowns?

Comment: Just write: `<select data-bind="options: $parent.contactFields, optionsText: 'AttributeType'">` ... http://jsfiddle.net/BHfyk/

Comment: Magic! Do you know where I read about this in the docs? Also please add an answer so I can give you tick. Thanks mate

Comment: You can check it here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `optionsText` you need to pass in property name as a string, in your case `'AttributeType'`:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.contactFields, optionsText: 'AttributeType'">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHfyk/).

This is described in documentation of the options binding: [Drop-down list representing arbitrary JavaScript objects, not just strings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example_3_dropdown_list_representing_arbitrary_javascript_objects_not_just_strings)

And later in the [parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#Parameters) section:

> `optionsText`
>
> See Example 3 above to see how you can bind options to an array of
>   arbitrary JavaScript object - not just strings. In this case, you need
>   to choose which of the objects’ properties should be displayed as the
>   text in the drop-down list or multi-select list. Example 3 shows how
>   you can specify that property name by passing an additional parameter
>   called optionsText.